# How to allow breaking lines at filtered content?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

Users at my website are able to write comments through special form. Field for value is a normal textarea. Now every comment is displayed without any html tags. It looks kinda weird when someone for instance post long comment. I would like to filter out value from all tags except new line chars (\n or \r\n).

I display that comments like that: `<%=h @comment.value %>`

What should I change? I was thinking about writing whole new method to filter all tags expect new line chars but I am sure that Ruby on Rails offers easier solution here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [`simple_format`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-simple_format) and `h`  together

```
<%= simple_format(h(@comment.value)) %>
```

`simple_format` essentially use `gsub` to convert line break into `<br>` and `<p>` tags.

Comment: You no longer need to specify the h method if it is Rails 3 (as the question is tagged) as this is done by default.